# sourcing .vimrc file put square brackets around file icons

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree, plugin-devicons

Whenever I try to source `~/.vimrc` file when NERDTree is open, I get square brackets around the file icons like so:

[image: square brackets around file icons]

Is there a way to get rid of them? Is it a bug?

I have already [posted this question on the NERDTree github repo](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/557), but have not received any answer yet.

UPDATE: I have opened [an issue with the vim-devicons project](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons/issues/154) about this.

Comment: It seems that it is a predefined functionality. By the image you have posted, I guess square brackets serves like cursor and when you move across, [* ] shows that your cursor is in that file. Does it causes any issue for you?

Comment: Gotcha. Your question made it seem as if you have no idea how the icons got there. You should contact the authors of vim-devicons if you don't want these brackets to be there, as it seems to be the [default behavior](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons) (see screenshot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting this in your `vimrc` **should** fix the re-source issue:

```
" after a re-source, fix syntax matching issues (concealing brackets):
if exists('g:loaded_webdevicons')
    call webdevicons#refresh()
endif
```

Comment: did not work for me. I tried calling it manually and that did not help (even `hardRefresh`)